# Issues with jQuery Mobile $.mobile.changePage function

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using `$.mobile.changePage()` to change move from a login page to a home page.  From there, none of the links on the home page work.  Those links are all using the standard href link.  I tried just using an `href=""` link for the login button as well and that works but the problem is, once the login button is clicked, I need to do some sort of login process to make sure that they entered in the right stuff and as far as I know, the href just happens immediately and I cannot make it wait or stop all together.  I tried using the `event.preventDefault()` but that would not stop the href from switching the page before the login checking was done.  Anyone have any ideas on how to solve my situation?  I am pretty new to jQuery Mobile so I dont fully understand every detail about it yet.  Also I am working with some legacy code at the moment and that code uses jQuery mobile alpha 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

How are you checking for the data from the login page? If you are only using javascript, you could just add an `onClick()` handler on the login button, and get the values from the fields with `document.getElementByID()`. AFTER that you could do `$.mobile.changePage()`.

Or maybe I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am currently doing the `onClick()` function call and doing the `$.mobile.changePage()` only.  I have not added in the login checking yet because I wanted to make sure I had the UI stuff down.  The issue is that the `href="#accountPage"` in the <a> tag does not work after the page has been changed with `$.mobile.changePage()`.  Does that make it clearer?